# Do I need to escape number in this shortcode function?

Tags: shortcode

This is the function:

```
function shortcode_output($atts) {
return do_shortcode('[ks_tab col="'.$atts['num'].'"][/ks_tab]');
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'shortcode_output');
```

People would add a number (only number) when using my shortcode, do I need to escape it so that it accepts only numbers?

Comment: Yes, never trust user input.

Comment: @SallyCJ Why not post it as an answer?

Comment: thanks, Sally....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, never trust user's input.**

Just because you told people to provide a valid number for a specific shortcode parameter, it doesn't guarantee that the input will always be a valid number, so always secure user's input — and output.

You should also, if you haven't already done so, read these articles:

- [Data Validation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/data-validation/)
- [Securing Input](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-input/)
- [Securing Output](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/security/securing-output/)

And for example in your case, for accepting absolute integers only:

```php
<?php
$cols = absint( $atts['num'] );
// Validate and set default value.
$cols = $cols ? $cols : 3;
```